# Checking the argument passed to the `AttributeUsageAttribute` constructor

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I want to check whether an attribute type has the `AttributeUsage` attribute applied to it *and* whether `AttributeTargets.Class` is passed to the `AttributeUsage` constructor. Here is the code I have written to perform the check:

```
bool CheckSomeArbitraryConditionMet(AttributeData attributeData)
{
    AttributeData[] attributeUsages =
        attributeData.AttributeClass.GetAttributes().Where(
            a => a.AttributeClass.Name == "AttributeUsageAttribute").ToArray();

    if (attributeUsages.Any())
    {
        return
            attributeUsages.Any(
                a =>
                    a.ConstructorArguments.Any(constant => constant.Value != null && constant.Value.ToString().Contains("AttributeTargets.Class"))
                    || a.NamedArguments.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.ToString().Contains("AttributeTargets.Class")));
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have an attribute as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Struct|AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

When I pass the `AttributeData` object representing `MyAttribute` to the `CheckSomeArbitraryConditionMet(AttributeData data)` method as defined above, the method returns `false` instead of `true`.

I set a breakpoint on the `if (attributeUsages.Any())` line and executed the following code in `Immediate Window`:

```
var attribute = attributeUsages.Single();
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
var constructorArguments = attribute.ConstructorArguments;
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
var argument = constructorArguments.Single();
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
var argumentValue = argument.Value;
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
var argumentValueString = argumentValue.ToString();
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
```

Here are their values when I inspected the `Locals` window:

[image]

As you can see, `argumentValue` is `76` and `argumentValueString` is `"76"`. So no wonder the `CheckSomeArbitraryConditionMet(AttributeData data)` method returns `false`!

How can I check whether `AttributeTargets.Class` is passed to the `AttributeUsage` constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the example on [the Enum.TryParse() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) as inspiration, and modified the implementation of `CheckSomeArbitraryConditionMet(AttributeData data)` to the following:

```
bool CheckSomeArbitraryConditionMet(AttributeData attributeData)
{
    AttributeData[] attributeUsages =
        attributeData.AttributeClass.GetAttributes().Where(
            a => a.AttributeClass.Name == "AttributeUsageAttribute").ToArray();

    if (attributeUsages.Any())
    {
        return
            attributeUsages.Any(
                attributeUsage =>
                    attributeUsage.ConstructorArguments.Any(
                        arg =>
                        {
                            string argValue = arg.Value.ToString();

                            return
                                arg.Kind == TypedConstantKind.Enum
                                && arg.Type.Name == "AttributeTargets"
                                && Enum.TryParse(argValue, ignoreCase: false, out AttributeTargets parsedValue)
                                && parsedValue == AttributeTargets.Class | parsedValue.ToString().Split(',').Contains("Class");
                        }));
    }
    return true;
}
```

This new implementation returns `true` (exactly as I want) when I pass the `AttributeData` object representing `MyAttribute` to the method.